# Tests don't work in Flutter Web application with Firebase plugin

Tags: firebase, testing, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I created Flutter Web application. I am using Firebase plugin. The application works in browser, but when I am trying to run tests I am getting compilation error related to Firebase plugin.

When I commented out the code related to Firebase plugin then a test is passing.

This is my pubspec.yaml:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase: 5.0.4
  flutter_bloc: ^0.21.0
  meta: ^1.1.6

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

When I run tests I am getting:

```
Compiler message:
../../../AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-5.0.4/lib/src/utils.dart:2:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html' show promiseToFuture;
```

So basically when running tests I don't have `dart:html` package imported. However when I start app normally everything works fine.

Can you help me with importing this package for tests?

Answer (score 1):

By default, `pub run test` (or clicking the "Run Tests" button on your IDE) runs tests on the Dart VM. But because of the `dart:html` import in the Firebase package, you need to **run the tests on a browser**, not Dart VM.

For example:

```
pub run test -p chrome path/to/test.dart
```

If all of your tests are in the `/test` folder, you can just say `pub run test -p chrome`.

Read more here: https://pub.dev/packages/test#running-tests

Comment: The issue is with the dart sdk and the firebase plugin. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/42408

Comment: In the meantime I upgraded flutter (I'm now on Flutter 1.10.15-pre.218 - channel master). And now when I am running tests using "Run Tests" button then they're passing. But when I am using the command that you suggested then I'm getting compilation error: Failed to load "path/to/test.dart": dart2js failed.

Comment: I found out that when I run widget tests (with testWidgets function) using 'Run Tests' button, then they're passing. But when I run unit tests (with test function) then I have the same error that I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @IiroKrankka your answer worked for me. Thank you! Is this the `dart:html` import you're talking about: [firebase-dart/lib/src/top_level.dart](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-dart/blob/master/lib/src/top_level.dart)? And how did you know it was there? I had to dig deep to find it and only because you told me it was there.